# Compute the probability of a joint event involving two independent standard normals

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, standard normal random variables. I'm trying to compute the probability of the event
$$
\{X \leq x, Y \leq kX\}
$$
where $k$ is a positive constant. The probability is given by the integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^{ks} \phi(t)\,\phi(s)\, dt \, ds
$$

where

$$
\phi(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^2}
$$

I'm only able to find a closed form solution when $k = 1$. Is it possible to obtain a closed form solution for arbitrary $k > 0$? I've tried the usual integration tools but seem to be coming up empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Many people do not consider expressions in $\Phi$ to be truly 'closed form'.

Comment: Actually, when $k=1$ the result is $\frac12\Phi(x)^2$, not $2\varphi(x)\Phi(x)$. Other particular values are $\min\{\Phi(x),\frac12\}$ when $k\to-\infty$, $\frac12\Phi(x)$ when $k=0$, and $(\Phi(x)-\frac12)^+$ when $k\to+\infty$. Additionally, for every $(k,x)$, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}P(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant kX)=-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{1+k^2}\varphi(x\sqrt{1+k^2}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Just as we must rely on printed tables (or numerical integration) to get most univariate normal probabilities, it is difficult to get closed forms for many multivatiate normal probabilities. There may be a
trick I don't know to handle the particular case of this Problem, but my impression is that such problems are often handled via 'zonal polynomials'.

For an uncorrelated bivariate normal distribution, simulation is
especially easy. Here is an approximation based on a million
simulated points with $x = 1$ and $k = 2$. The answer should be
correct to 2 or 3 decimal places.

```
 m = 10^6;  x = 1;  k = 2
 z1 = rnorm(m);  z2 = rnorm(m)
 mean(z1 < x & z2 < 2*z1)
 ## 0.342797
```

The dark points in the plot below satisfy the desired condition.

[image]

Comment: Yeah it's probably easier to obtain a numerical approximation using the Gauss-Hermite quadrature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature

Comment: For a case where the normals are not independent see 'http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598940'.